# What is the issue with Wayland essentially not working on 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, wayland

I was excited to learn that Wayland *was* the the default.

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and the default is still X.

If I choose Wayland when I login (from the greeter) my system slows down to an almost unusable level.

I can move the cursor but anytime I move over any object where there would be a highlighting action, my entire computer screeches to a halt so it is not usable.

I have an Nvidia graphics card with the `430` driver.

Is there an update or reason I why Wayland is running so poorly, or how I can make it workable for my machine?

Comment: "I have read that Wayland is now the default for Ubuntu 19.10" ... where did you read this?

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/ubuntu-confirm-wayland-default-17-10
I see that says 17.10 not 19.10, but - why would they ever go backwards on this?

Comment: *"Why would they ever go backwards on this":* they went back to defaulting to X11 in 18.04, because Wayland had, well, issues; as you have noticed.

Comment: From your description, you DID enable and use Wayland. It didn't work well for you,

Comment: Wayland is about 10 year project to replace the 30+ year Xorg. You have to be patient and hope more people jump on the Wayland bandwagon to accelerate developers' interests.

Comment: Wayland still does not work with Nvidia proprietary drivers, and in 19.10, unlike in 18.04, will not switch automatically to the intergrated (Intel i915 etc.) drivers.  On my 19.10, Wayland isn't offered at the login when Nvidia proprietary drivers are in use, so you must be using the nouveau driver, not noted for the highest performance.

Answer (score 1):

Wayland is the default for the graphical login screen only, as can be seen in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` :

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Another, possibly more convincing way to see that Wayland is actually used by your login screen :

1. Go to the login screen : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, or choose to login as another user, to have gdm open it again.
2. Go back to an already opened graphical session, or open a text session on one of the VTs.
3. In a terminal, type `loginctl`. You will notice a session opened by user `gdm`. That's the session corresponding to the login screen. Take note of its session ID.
4. Type `loginctl show-session session_id --property Type`
5. Convinced ?

Concerning Nvidia, the latest driver available on Ubuntu is 435, not 430. I said on Ubuntu (to date), not the latest Nvidia driver to date.

My reply would better fit in the comments, but heh, not enough rep...

Comment: "Wayland is the default for the graphical login screen only" I don't believe this is true - can you provide a source?

Comment: I said I had the lastest 430 driver, not the latest period and technically the latest driver is 440 - not that it really matters. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Nmath : Sure. Have a look at your `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. I'm going to update my answer to reflect this.

@Startec : You're right, the latest Nvidia driver version is 440.31, but it's not available on Ubuntu yet, as can be seen from an `apt list 'nvidia-driver*'`. That's why I added *on Ubuntu*.

Comment: Personally I don't care about Wayland for a year or two yet, but upvoting just so you get more "rep".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix : Ah thanks, I suppose it was only a matter of time before I finally can "comment everywhere", but the sooner the better !

Comment: You can edit questions and answers and make two points each time. You can post questions and make 5 points with each upvote. It takes awhile but can turn into a nice little hobby making points. The side benefit is learning from others and making your computer system run smoother and more powerful with added functionality.

Comment: @NovHak Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a liveUSB.  The first line is uncommented `WaylandEnable=false`. This makes GDM3 use X.org.  In 18.04.3 there is no default use of wayland

Comment: @Nmath : I was assuming (wrongly it turns out) that you were running 19.10, since that's what is mentioned in the question. Otherwise things may be different of course.

Comment: @NovHak good point.  to be sure I checked also on a liveUSB of 19.10 -- it is also the same there, wayland not enabled by default https://i.imgur.com/CXhrSFR.png

Comment: @Nmath Same applies to the 19.04 live system. However, on a regular, installed 19.10, Wayland is enabled by default on the login screen.